# Is $\frac{1}{x} = 4$ strictly a linear equation (in one variable)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac1{x} = 4$$
If multiplied by $x$ both sides,
$$1 = 4x$$
Then it looks like linear equation in one variable. But is such multiplication by variable on both sides allowed?

Comment: No, it is not, but it can be transformed into a linear equation except that $x$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: Whenever you multiply with (or divide by) an expression containing $x$, you must be careful that this expression is not $0$. Many fake proofs are based on "division by $0$" or "multiplication with $0$"

Comment: $x$ is an unknown, but is not a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions are equivalent within the condition that $x\neq 0$ indeed for $x=0$ we would obtain

- $\frac1{0} = 4$
- $1=0$

which are undefined.

We can observe that as equations in the unknown $x$ they are equivalent in the sense that they lead to the same solution $x=\frac14$.

Otherwise for the expressions $\frac {x^3}{x}=1$ and $x^3=x$ are not equivalent as equations because $x=0$ is a solution for the second one but not for the first one.